# setRowFactory on TableView updateItem - style -fx-font-weight: bold not working

Tags: javafx

For some reason when I want to make a row bold it's not working. Same if I try setting the style on the children.  I think this was working in the past. I'm on the latest 11.0.2 version.

see below for my testing code. I can use color though. Color works, font doesn't.

Thanks!

```
emailsTableView.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<EmailMessage>, TableRow<EmailMessage>>() {
    @Override
    public TableRow<EmailMessage> call(TableView<EmailMessage> param) {
        return new TableRow<>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(EmailMessage item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item != null) {
                    if (item.isRead()) {
                        setStyle("");
                    } else {
                        //setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
                        //setStyle("fx-font-style: italic");
                        //setStyle("-fx-background-color: purple");
                        for (int i=0; i < getChildren().size(); i++) {
                            getChildren().get(i).setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
                            //getChildren().get(i).setStyle("-fx-background-color: purple");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("setupBoldRows " + item + " style: " + getStyle());
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you the exact cause for your issue (as i am not working on JavaFX 11 environment). But I would like you to give a try with css styleSheet to see if that is working.

In your css file :

```
.table-row-cell:unread{
  -fx-font-weight:bold;
}
```

In Code:

```
// Create a unread pseudo state for row.
final PseudoClass unreadPseudoState = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unread");

emailsTableView.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<EmailMessage>, TableRow<EmailMessage>>() {
    @Override
    public TableRow<EmailMessage> call(TableView<EmailMessage> param) {
      return new TableRow<>() {
          @Override
          protected void updateItem(EmailMessage item, boolean empty) {
              super.updateItem(item, empty);
              if (item != null) {
                  // Update the pseudo state of the row to pick the styling from styleSheet
                  this.pseudoClassStateChanged(unreadPseudoState, !item.isRead());
              }
          }
      };
    }
});
```

Comment: I think it's a Mac issue. I copied the project and went back to Java 8 and it didn't work there. And I went to the course github and got the final code and it didn't work there either.  The course author was working on Linux. Course code is here https://github.com/barosanuemailtest/JavaFxEmailClientCourse